# Why is express.basicAuth not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am successfully running this line of code on an old express binary install, but now when setting up an ELB on AWS the line is failing with the following error. I am running the following versions of packages. This is the code running on production and is unchanged so I know it isn't the code. The version of express I am running on production is from 2015. The version I am getting this error on is below (i.e., late 2016).

PACKAGES:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "aws-sdk": "<=2.149.0",
    "express": "<=4.14.0",
    "forever": "<=0.15.3",
    "socket.io-client": "<=1.5.1",
    "kue": "<=0.11.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2"
  }
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError: express.basicAuth is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/server.js:1160:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
/var/app/current/server.js:1160
app.use(express.basicAuth('user', '5a9d232349459459479'));
```

CODE:

```
// start the UI
var app = express();
app.use(express.basicAuth('user', '8a4444444444479')); <-- error
```

Comment: Have you looked at the "How to use" section? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth

Comment: yes I have. Again, I am using it in the same way as our production server which runs fine.